# Maximum cost of traversal in matrix using dynamic programming

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Suppose I've a `m x n` matrix in Java.

I want to find the maximum traversal cost from first column to last column. Each value represents the cost incurred. I'm allowed to travel in up, down and right directions across the matrix. Each cell can be visited only once. Transitions are allowed from a top cell of a column to the bottom of the same and vice-versa.

For simplicity, consider the following matrix:

```
2 3 17
4 1 -1
5 0 14
```

If I'm supposed to find the maximum cost, my answer would be 46 (2 → 5 → 4 → 1 → 3 → 0 → 14 → 17).

I've tried to solve this problem using dynamic approach using the following recursive relation:

```
maxCost(of destination node) = max{ maxCost(at neighbouring node 1), maxCost(at neighbouring node 2), maxCost(at neighbouring node 3) } + cost(of destination node)
```

In this case, it would be something like:

```
maxCost(17) = max{ maxCost(3), maxCost(-1), maxCost(14) } + 17;
```

Since, each cell is allowed to be visited only once, I understand that I would need to maintain a corresponding `m x n` `isVisited` matrix. However, I can't figure out how to maintain `isVisited` matrix. The matrix would be modified when maxCost(3) is calculated; but for maxCost(-1) and maxCost(14), I would require its initial status (which would be lost).

Is my approach correct for this problem? Also, I can't figure out how should my functions look like.
(This is my first attempt at dynamic programming).

Comment: Wouldn't the maximum in your example actually be: 2→5→4→1→3→0→14→17 = 46 ?

Comment: You're right. Didn't see that! Will edit it. Thank you. :)

Comment: I'm not sure dynamic programming is the best choice here. I would rather use a pathfinding algorithm such as A*

Comment: @Dici I was thinking of using [Johnson's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm), but I really wanted to learn DP. Gives a lot of boost if you can solve your first one. :)

Comment: @NikunjMadhogaria I just don't feel a strong fit for DP. I'll try it with A* and tell you :p How large is the matrix expected to get ?

Comment: @Dici the limit is `500 x 500`.

Comment: @NikunjMadhogaria A* is actually a worse choice than anything, because it is fitted to find the shortest path while we are looking for the longest one here :D Back to thinking...

Comment: @Dici I've posted a solution using recursion. Let me know what you think about it. ;)

Comment: @NikunjMadhogaria I will look at it. I need some time to read all the answers. You guys have been smarter than me on this one haha

Comment: @Dici Sure! Haha.. :D

Comment: So can you go from any spot in the first column to any spot in the last column? It doesn't have to be top-left to top-right?

Comment: @Dici just negate all the costs and you suddenly have a least cost problem ;-)

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom Yes. You have to find the maximum cost starting from any position in first column and ending at last column.

Comment: @NikunjMadhogaria you mean my proposition of mutating the matrix and discarding the changes at the end ? Did you try it ?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom I thought about that. Well, I could try

Comment: @Dici Oh, that was meant for ErickG.Hagstrom. Sorry, I got jumbled up in comments! :P I replied regarding that aspect in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's a tough one. Notice that since your path cannot repeat visited cells your possible paths would have 'snake'-like behavior such as:

[image]

The idea is to store in `f[j][i]` the maximum length of paths that end at the cell `(j, i)`. Lets say now that we want to transition from `f[j][i-1]` to `f[j'][i]`.  We can, then, either choose to go from cell `(j, i)` to cell `(j', i)` directly or we could go from cell `(j, i)` to cell `(j', i)` by wrapping around the top/botton edge. So the update for `f[j][i]`, then, could be calculated as:

[image]

where

[image]

Here `a` is the given array.

The problem now is how to calculate `sum(a[j..j'][i]` effectively since otherwise the runtime would be `O(m^3n)`. You can solve this by using a temporary variable `tmp_sum` for the `sum(a[j..j'][i])` which you increment as you increment `j`. The runitme of algorithm then would be `O(m^2 n)`.

Here is an sample implementation:

```
package stackoverflow;

public class Solver {

    int m, n;
    int[][] a, f;

    public Solver(int[][] a) {
        this.m = a.length;
        this.n = a[0].length;
        this.a = a;
    }

    void solve(int row) {
        f = new int[m][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                f[i][j] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
                sum += a[j][i];
            for (int j1 = 0; j1 < m; ++j1) {
                int tmp_sum = 0;
                boolean first = true;
                for (int j2 = j1; j2 != j1 || first; j2 = (j2+1)%m) {
                    if (first)
                        first = false;
                    tmp_sum += a[j2][i];
                    int best_sum = Math.max(tmp_sum, sum - tmp_sum +a[j1][i]+a[j2][i]);
                    if (j1 == j2)
                        best_sum = a[j1][i];
                    int prev = 0;
                    if (i > 0)
                        prev = f[j1][i-1];
                    f[j2][i] = Math.max(f[j2][i], best_sum + prev);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(f[row][n-1]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Solver(new int[][]{{2, 3, 17}, {4, 1, -1}, {5, 0, 14}}).solve(0); //46
        new Solver(new int[][]{{1, 1}, {-1, -1}}).solve(0); //2
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure with the arguments of your max ? Also, could you give more explicit names to `a` and `f` ? I'm interested in understanding your answer

Comment: @Dici I'm sure. In the one the sum starts at `j` and ends in `j'` in the next argument is the other way around. If you have `a[0..5]` then `sum(a[1..3]) = s[1] + s[2] + s[3]` and `sum(a[3..1]) = s[3] + s[4] + s[5] + s[0] + s[1]`. I know that I didn't explain it explicitly enough but I don't have time at the moment. However, I have intention to improve it in the future so ask any question you may have.

Comment: Well, ok, I'll come back to the answer. The first thing to do, to me, would be to stop using random notations such as `f`, `s`, and `a` and give them meaningful names. Your answer seems interesting, so it would be great to make it easy to read. Good luck, and don't hesitate commenting your own question to remind me to see your edits

Comment: @svs can you please comment your code in solve()? Also, where do you take the input for destination cell. Does it work only for top-right most cell?

Comment: @NikunjMadhogaria Sure but it would be later this day, since I'm busy at the moment. `solve` actually calculates the max path among all paths at the moment. This can easily be fixed by just printing `f[i][n-1]` instead if want to get the max path that end in `i-th` row. i will notify you when I edit it and make it easier to explain. Until then you could just use print statement to figure out how it works.

Comment: Sure. I'll give it a try. :)

Comment: @NikunjMadhogaria I hope that now is understandable.

Comment: @svs thanks again for your inputs. I've posted my solution. Please let me know your views if possible. :)

Comment: @svs sorry, it took me a while to have some time for this. Interesting answer. Just as a note, isn't it confusing to denote the cells as `(j, i)` instead of the classical `(i, j)`. I would get it on an image, where we often use `(w, h)`, but sounds weird on a plain array. Anyway, it's a detail, +1 :p

Comment: @svs your last `for` loop is also a bit unclear. It takes a few seconds to get your intention. I would use a `do-while` instead, I think it's much more readable

Comment: @svs is your complexity really `O(m^2 n)` ? You have 4 nested loops performing respectively `n`, `m`, `m`, `m` iterations so it's a `O(m^3 n)`. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Dici they are actually 3 nested loops. It's one outer for loop, followed by one 1 inner for loop and 1 inner double for loop. The complexity is `O(n m) + O(n m^2) = O(n m^2)`. Basically `for { for{}; for{for{}};`}

Comment: @svs ohhh my bad, don't know why, I thought it was just badly indented when I scanned the code. Sorry, you're right

Answer (score 4):

This is a nice and slightly tricky problem. For a DP solution, we must phrase it in a way that comports with the [principle of optimality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation).

This requires us to define a "state" so that the problem can be written in terms of an n-way decision that takes us to a new state that, in turn, is a new, smaller version of the same problem.

A suitable choice for state is the current position of the traversal plus a signed integer f that says where and how many untraversed (I'll call them "free") rows there are in the current column.  We can write this as a triple [i,j,f].

The value of f tells us whether it's okay to move up and/or down. (Unless we're in the right column, it's always possible to move right, and it's never possible to move left.) If f is negative, there are f free rows "above" the current position, which may wrap around to the matrix bottom. If positive, there are `f` free rows below. Note that f=m-1 and f=1-m mean the same thing: all rows are free except the current position's. For simplicity, we'll use f==m-1 to represent that case.

The single integer f is all we need to describe free spaces because we can only only traverse in steps of size 1, and we never move left. Ergo there can't be non-contiguous groups of free spaces in the same column.

Now the DP "decision" is a 4-way choice:

1. Stand pat at the current square: only valid in the last column.
2. Move up: only valid if there's free space above.
3. Move down: only valid if there's free space below.
4. Move right: valid except in the last column.

Let, C(t) be the max cost function in the DP, where t is a triple [i,j,f]. Then the max cost we can achieve is the cost A[i,j] from the matrix added to the cost of the rest of the traversal after making the optimum decision 1 to 4 above. The optimum decision is just the one that produces the highest cost!

All this makes C the max of a set where all the elements are conditional.

```
C[i,j,f] = max { A[i,j] if j==n-1, // the "stand pat" case
               { A[i,j]+C[i,j+1,m-1] if j<n-1  // move right
               { A[i,j]+C[i+1,j,f-1] if f>0    // move down
               { A[i,j]+C[i-1,j,2-m] if f==m-1 // first move in col is up
               { A[i,j]+C[i-1,j,f+1] if f<0    // other moves up
```

Sometimes words are clearer than algebra. The "down" case would be...

> One potential max path cost from position [i,j] to the goal (right column) is the matrix value A[i,j] plus the max cost obtainable by moving down to position [i+1,j]. But we can move down only if there are free spaces there (f>0). After moving down, there's one less of those (f-1).

This explains why the recursive expression is C[i+1,j,f-1]. The other cases are just variations of this.

Also note that the "base cases" are implicit above. In all states where f=0 and j=n-1, you have them. The recursion must stop.

To get the final answer, you must consider the max over all valid starting positions, which are the first column elements, and with all other elements in the column free: `max C[i,0,m-1]` for i=0..m-1.

Since you were unsuccessful with finding a DP, here is a table-building code to show it works. The dependencies in the DP require care in picking the evaluation order. Of course the `f` parameter can be negative, and the row parameter wraps. I took care of these in 2 functions that adjust f and i. Storage is O(m^2):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MaxPath {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a = {
      {2, 3, 17},
      {4, 1, -1},
      {5, 0, 14}
    };
    System.out.println(new Dp(a).cost());
  }
}

class Dp {
  final int[][] a, c;
  final int m, n;

  Dp(int[][] a) {
    this.a = a;
    this.m = a.length;
    this.n = a[0].length;
    this.c = new int[2 * m - 2][m];
  }

  int cost() {
    Arrays.fill(c[fx(m - 1)], 0);
    for (int j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      // f = 0
      for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        c[fx(0)][i] = a[i][j] + c[fx(m - 1)][i];
      }
      for (int f = 1; f < m - 1; f++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
          c[fx(-f)][i] = max(c[fx(0)][i], a[i][j] + c[fx(1 - f)][ix(i - 1)]);
          c[fx(+f)][i] = max(c[fx(0)][i], a[i][j] + c[fx(f - 1)][ix(i + 1)]);
        }
      }
      // f = m-1
      for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        c[fx(m - 1)][i] = max(c[fx(0)][i], 
            a[i][j] + c[fx(m - 2)][ix(i + 1)], 
            a[i][j] + c[fx(2 - m)][ix(i - 1)]);
      }
      System.out.println("j=" + j + ": " + Arrays.deepToString(c));
    }
    return max(c[fx(m - 1)]);
  }
  // Functions to account for negative f and wrapping of i indices of c.
  int ix(int i) { return (i + m) % m; }
  int fx(int f) { return f + m - 2; }
  static int max(int ... x) { return Arrays.stream(x).max().getAsInt(); }
}
```

Here's the output. If you understand the DP, you can see it building optimal paths backward from column j=2 to j=0. The matrices are indexed by f=-1,0,1,2 and i=0,1,2.

```
j=2: [[31, 16, 14], [17, -1, 14], [17, 13, 31], [31, 30, 31]]
j=1: [[34, 35, 31], [34, 31, 31], [34, 32, 34], [35, 35, 35]]
j=0: [[42, 41, 44], [37, 39, 40], [41, 44, 42], [46, 46, 46]]
46
```

The result shows (j=0, column f=m-1=2) that all elements if the first column are equally good as starting points.

Comment: Although I didn't understand completely, thanks alot for your input. :)

Comment: @NikunjMadhogaria I explained in more detail. Will try to code this if I get some time.

Comment: Please check my answer. I think I somewhat implemented your algorithm. However, I doubt whether it's the *best* solution. Let me know your views if possible. :)

Comment: @Gene I like that your answer tries to rationalize and a general methodology for approaching a DP problem

Comment: @NikunjMadhogaria It's fairly obviously O(m^2 n) if implemented correctly (because f is O(m)).  I'm pretty sure you can't do asymptotically better.

Comment: @NikunjMadhogaria Looked at your solution. Probably fine, but it's not really a DP solution as you requested. For DP code, you'd be using either memoized recursion or a table(array) filled in dependency order. What  you have is closer to an exhaustive search approach.

Comment: @Gene Yes. You're right. It is an exhaustive search. I couldn't find a DP way to solve it by memoized recursion or an array filled in dependency order. Any ideas how can I tweak my code to improve on it?

Comment: @Gene Can you please explain the need of `first move in col is up` case?

Comment: @Gene  I like your answer. But still struggling to understand the DP code. Will go through it carefully.

Comment: @NikunjMadhogaria Certainly if f<0, then there is free space above, so a move up is okay. But there's one other case where a move up is okay: f=m-1, where all spaces in the column are free except (i,j) [remember we're not using f=1-m to avoid two representations for the same thing]. So moving up one produces the case 2-m: a negative number connoting m-2 free spaces above. this is where we get C(i-1,j,2-m)

Comment: @NikunjMadhogaria Incidentally, you picked a tricky case for your first DP.  Seeing how DP fits a problem is for most people a skill learned by practice starting with easy examples. Consider hunting SO and other sources for some of these.

Comment: @Gene Thanks a lot for the support! I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @NikunjMadhogaria For what it's worth, it occurred to me that there was no need for 2 arrays. I was able to simplify things quite a lot.

Comment: @Gene I'll go through it; will accept your answer once I fully understand the code. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone for your contributions.

I've come up with a solution using `recursive` technique using `system stack`. I think that my solution is relatively easier to understand.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatrixTraversal {

    static int[][] cost;
    static int m, n, maxCost = 0;

    public static void solve(int currRow, int currCol, int[][] isVisited, int currCost) {

        int upperRow, lowerRow, rightCol;
        isVisited[currRow][currCol] = 1;

        currCost += cost[currRow][currCol];             //total cost upto current position

        if( currCol == (n - 1)                          //if we have reached the last column in matrix
            && maxCost < currCost )                     //and present cost is greater than previous maximum cost
            maxCost = currCost;

        upperRow = ((currRow - 1) + m) % m;             //upper row value taking care of teleportation
        lowerRow = (currRow + 1) % m;                   //lower row value taking care of teleportation
        rightCol = currCol + 1;                         //right column value

        if( isVisited[upperRow][currCol] == 0 )     //if upper cell has not been visited
            solve(upperRow, currCol, isVisited, currCost);

        if( isVisited[lowerRow][currCol] == 0 )     //if lower cell has not been visited
            solve(lowerRow, currCol, isVisited, currCost);

        if( rightCol != n &&                            //if we are not at the last column of the matrix
            isVisited[currRow][rightCol] == 0 )     //and the right cell has not been visited
            solve(currRow, rightCol, isVisited, currCost);

        isVisited[currRow][currCol] = 0;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] isVisited;
        int i, j;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the no.of rows(m): ");
        m = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the no.of columns(n): ");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        cost = new int[m][n];
        isVisited = new int[m][n];

        System.out.println("Enter the cost matrix:");
        for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
                cost[i][j] = sc.nextInt();              //generating the cost matrix

        for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
            solve(i, 0, isVisited, 0);                  //finding maximum traversal cost starting from each cell in 1st column 

        System.out.println(maxCost);

    }

}
```

However, I'm not sure whether this is the best and the fastest way to compute the solution.

Please let me know your views. I'll accept this as answer accordingly.

Comment: Makes more sense to have `isVisited` as a matrix of `boolean` since you're not writing in C :) By the way I think it works but has a huge memory cost both on the heap and on the stack. Remind that you can only open a few thousands of method contexts in Java (typically less than 10 000). Other languages allow for deeper recursions but Java is clearly limited to small recursive problems. The fact of copying `isVisited` over and over also comes with a high run time cost. Apart from that, the solution is compact and clear

Comment: Using a static max cost is inelegant a non thread-safe. Should probably be returned by `solve`.

Comment: Yes, of course. `isVisited` can be made of `boolean` type. The memory cost was one of the major concerns I found in my solution. Since arrays are passed by reference in Java, I'm *forced* to create a `new` `isVisitedCopy`. Is there any way I can avoid this memory cost by using some `pass by value` technique instead? Yes, `maxCost` can be returned by `solve`. :) Also, what would be the time complexity of my solution in big - O notation?

Comment: If you mean like in C++, this would just perform an implicit copy, but still copy the array. Also note that `boolean` take less space in memory than `int` (it depends of the JVM but let's assume it takes 8 bits, you're saving 24 * m * n bits everytime. You could even use `byte` but maybe not a good idea for clarity

Comment: Thanks for your insight! So, am I bound to create a copy of `isVisited` in Java?

Comment: I think it is possible to change it before all subsequent calls, and discard the change at the end of the method in order to simulate immutability

Comment: So you suggest moving the copy action to the end of function after all the possible moves from a position are made, right?

Comment: Nope, what I'm saying is that you can prevent making copies of the array and as your last instruction you do `isVisited[currRow][currCol] = 0;` to put the array back to the state it was before entering the method. This way, you discard all the changes you made to it, which is equivalent to immutability from the point of view of the person who calls the method. I tried with your particular example, it still returns `46`

Comment: I think that works because the same score can be obtained starting from `2` (first cell of first column) and as a result we already have max cost of `46`.

Comment: Just try it : https://gist.github.com/Dicee/9826814ac6845627a3d1. I tried it on other examples, seems accurate, and it never performs a copy of the array

Comment: Please update it. At some instances `m` needs to be replaced by `n`. Check edit in my answer. I'll check some cases. :)

Comment: Yeah I was finding a case weird were the program returns a solution I wasn't able to achieve manually

Comment: Right! :) I had initially written a solution using `n x m`. Just copied it here to realize that forgot to make some necessary changes.

Comment: Yes. I saw your comment (some case with a lot of -1). After which I lost one of my votes. :P

Comment: Hahaha that's ok I've had a doubt. Looks like it definitely works, and so does my version without copy, at least on all examples I tried

Comment: Yes. Even I tested. It seems to work. Still skeptical. Perhaps I'll try tracing the path and see that the cost is updated accordingly. Any ideas which answer is best here, so that I could accept one? Or should I wait for some more attention?

Comment: To me iterative answers are better for large problems, recursion will eventually fail with a `StackOverflowError`. In terms of readability yours is better than svs's one. Gene does not give you an explicit answer but brings his reasoning very well (same for svs with his formulas) while you only bring code. Finally, you must prove that my proposition for avoiding copy is correct or incorrect because you cannot accept making those expensive copies if there is a possibility to avoid it

Comment: What you can already do is upvote all the answers that make sense because it was not an easy question and people spent a lot of time answering you. That deserves consideration

Comment: Thanks for making my problem statement more clear. :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91324/discussion-between-nikunj-madhogaria-and-dici).

Answer (score 1):

One possible optimization is that we only need to calculate different options (other than a full sum) for columns with negative numbers or sequences of non-negative columns less than `m` in length, enclosed by columns with negatives. We need one column and a (conceptual) matrix to compute the max for a sequence of such columns; a matrix for the current column that converts into a column of maximums for each exit point. Each matrix represents the maximum sum for entry at `y` and exit at `y'` combined with the previous max just preceding the entry point (there are two possibilities for each, depending on the path direction). The matrix is symmetrically reflected along the diagonal (meaning `sum entry...exit = sum exit...entry`) until the various previous maximums for each entry point are added.

Adding an additional column with negative numbers to the example, we can see how the cummulative sums may be applied:

```
2  3  17  -3
4  1  -1  15
5  0  14  -2
```

(We'll ignore the first two non-negative columns for now and add 15 later.)

```
Third column:

 y' 0  1  2
y 
0   17 30 31
1   30 -1 30
2   31 30 14
```

For the fourth column matrix, each entry point needs to be combined with the maximum for the same exit point from the previous column. For example, entry point `0` is added with `max(17,30,31)`:

```
 y' 0  1  2
y 
0   -3 12 10  + max(17,30,31)
1   12 15 13  + max(30,-1,30)
2   10 13 -2  + max(31,30,14)

       =

    28 43 41
    42 45 43
    41 44 29
```

We can see the final max has (entry,exit) `(1,1)` and solution:

```
15 + (0,1) or (2,1) + (1,1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! I've posted my solution. Please let me know your views if possible. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's see how the dynamic programming answers here differ from the brute-force approach in your answer, and how we may tweak yours. Take the simple example,

```
a = {{17, -3}
    ,{-1, 15}}
```

Brute-force will traverse and compare all paths:

```
17,-3
17,-3,15
17,-1,15
17,-1,15,-3

-1,15
-1,15,-3
-1,17,-3
-1,17,-3,15
```

The dynamic-programming solutions take advantage of the choice-point between columns since there is only one possibility there - move right. At each move between columns, the dynamic-programming solutions apply a pruning method, using the `max` function, that limits the search to proven higher cost paths over others.

The up-down choices in the recursive solution offered by Gene, lead to a similar traversal found in the loops in svs' solution, meaning choices between entry and exit in the same column will be pruned. Look again at our example:

```
a = {{17, -3}
    ,{-1, 15}}

f(-1) -> max(15,15 - 3)
      -> 17 -> max(-3,-3 + 15) 

f(17) -> max(-3,-3 + 15)
      -> -1 -> max(15,15 - 3)
```

There's no need to check the full path sum `-1,15,-3` or to check both `17 - 1 + 15` and `17 - 1 + 15 - 3` since in each case we already know which ending would be greater, thanks to the `max` function: `17 - 1 + 15`.

---

The matrix array solutions work slightly differently to the recursive but with a similar effect. We focus only on the move between columns, `j to j + 1`, which can only happen in one place, and we choose to add *only* the best sum so far up to `j` when we calculate `j + 1`. Look at the example:

```
a = {{17, -3}
    ,{-1, 15}}
```

Calculate the matrix of best sums for exit points along column `j = 0`, in `O(m^2)` time:

```
17
16
```

Now for `j = 1`, we calculate the best paths achievable only along column `j = 1` with exit points along column `j = 1`, remembering to add to these paths' entry points the previous best (meaning the number from the column immediately to the left, denoted with *):

```
best exit at -3 = max(-3 + 17*, 15 - 3 + 16*) = 28
best exit at 15 = max(15 + 16*, -3 + 15 + 17*) = 31
```

---

Now to tweak your version, think about how you could alter it so the recursion chooses at each step the greatest sum returned from among its subsequent calls.

Comment: In the first section using the `max` function, aren't we actually performing brute force too? Look at the values compared for `f(-1)`: when starting from `-1` -- -3, -3 + 15; when travelling via `17` -- 15, 15 - 3. This brings us to 4 number of comparisons -- same as that of brute force.

Comment: In second method, when we're finding best exit at `-3`, it would also depend on best exit at `15` (since we are allowed transitions). But, that at `15` also requires the knowledge of best exit at `-3`. Won't it lead to a paradox situation?

Comment: Regrading the recursion - you're right in that the example I gave may be too small to see a difference. Consider the following example with three choice points: `x -> a or b -> c or d`, which leads to the following recursive calculation: `x + max( max(c,d) + a, max(c,d) + b )` Instead of four threads: `x,a,c / x,a,d / x,b,c / x,b,d`, we have three: `f(3) = max(c,d) returned to f(2) = max(a + f(3), b + f(3)) returned to  f(1) = max(x + f(2), x + f(2))`. The larger the number of choice points, the greater the difference between brute-force and the dynamic program.

Comment: To your second question - there is only one best exit at `-3` and it does not depend on the best exit at `15`. We consider all the possible entry points to column `j = 1` with exits at `-3` and choose the best one. That choice does depend on the best sum just before the entry point, which is why we calculate the best preceding exit points from column `j = 0`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Really appreciate it. :)